# Limit collected points to three per level (Like the Stars in Angry Birds)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a 2D Mobile game in Unity and I have a scoring system similar to Angry Birds, where depending on the amount of projectiles you have left at the end of the level, you get between one and three "Runes". The Runes are saved in PlayerPrefs.

My question, is there a way to limit the collected Runes to three per level? At the moment they just keep counting up.

Below is the script I'm using to save the Runes, it's applied in each level.
Any Ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
#region Rune System

public void RuneCollection() 
{
    int currentRunes = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Runes", 0);

    if (currentSpears >= 2)
    {
        Debug.Log("3 runes collected!");
        collectedRunes = 3;
    }
    else if (currentSpears >= 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("2 runes collected!");
        collectedRunes = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("1 rune collected!");
        collectedRunes = 1;
    }

    currentRunes += collectedRunes;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Runes", currentRunes);
}

#endregion
```

Comment: yes, obviously by checking `currentRunes` after adding `collectedRunes` ... where is the problem ? ... but IMHO there should be different algorithm  - current should be max from current and collected

Comment: why it has +1? OP doesn't show any attempt to solve the problem by himself

Comment: Yeah but they are counted after each Level right, so if I were to play for example Level 1 three times it would keep counting up and Id have nine Runes instead of three. I feel like Im missing something there

Comment: yes, you are missing checking currentRunes after adding collectedRunes - if it's more then you need then you should set to the value that you need ... again where is the problem?

Comment: currentRunes checks all Runes collected across all Levels. So if I get one Rune in three Levels currentRunes would be the same as if I got three in one Level. But Ill look into it further. Guess Im just a bit dense. I appreciate the feedback

Comment: In general you shouldn't (ab)use PlayerPrefs to store user progress ... it's easy to lose and manipulate .. rather use proper FileIO and store your values in an (encrypted) file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep track of runes on every level, then you should make something like this

```
public void RuneCollection()
{
    var levelIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
    int currentRunes = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Runes" + levelIndex, 0);

    if (currentSpears >= 2)
    {
        Debug.Log("3 runes collected!");
        collectedRunes = 3;
    }
    else if (currentSpears >= 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("2 runes collected!");
        collectedRunes = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("1 rune collected!");
        collectedRunes = 1;
    }

    currentRunes += collectedRunes;
    if (currentRunes > 3) currentRunes = 3;
    
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Runes" + levelIndex, currentRunes);
}
```

You will have a record for every level in `PlayerPrefs` and player would not get more than 3 points on each level. I don't know how you change levels, so I made a basic lookup to scene index in build. If you have another system, then you should implement `levelIndex` variable by yourself.

Comment: Ah snap of course! Yeah I see what you mean. That'll work. Thanks. I appreciate it.